# How to keep only vertical lines on images with image-processing?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, scikit-image, opencv

I'm applying some filters on my image to keep only important information. The main information that i want to keep it's the vertical lines on the image, if they have of course. Is there some function to help me with that?

I have already applied the following filters in this order:

GRAY SCALE

CLOSING (Morphological Transformations)

CONVOLVE2D (signal by scipy)

SOBEL_X (To eliminate the horizontal lines)

THRESHOLD BINARY

```py
    def process_image(self):
        image = cv2.cvtColor(self.img_diagonal, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


        # Step 1 - Mophological Filters

        kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT,(5,5))

        closing = cv2.morphologyEx(image, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)


        scharr = np.array([[-3 - 3j, 0 - 10j, +3 - 3j],
                          [-10 + 0j, 0 + 0j, +10 + 0j],
                          [-3 + 3j, 0 + 10j, +3 + 3j]])  # Gx + j*Gy

        grad = signal.convolve2d(closing, scharr, boundary='symm', mode='same')


        sobelx = cv2.Sobel(np.absolute(grad), cv2.CV_64F, 1, 0, ksize=3)


        ret, thresh2 = cv2.threshold(sobelx, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

        cv2.imwrite("Temp/ritmo--%d.png" % self.count, thresh2)

        return thresh2
```

I expect to keep only the vertical lines on the following  images, The image on the right it's the base image, no processed, i want to apply some filters on the left image:

(I can't post image, so here the link)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWtPJ.png
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/Koa8F.png

Comment: Please do not post pictures of pictures, just post the pictures themselves otherwise we have to go around cropping out extraneous stuff before we can test our methods. Also, what is the difference between the two images you have posted please? And do you really mean to start on the right and work backwards to the left? And can you add an extra image with a red circle around whatever it is you are looking for please? Thank you!

Comment: Try dilation with a vertical structuring element.